# How to loop trought array and create array from common values?

Tags: php, arrays

i need to filter an array and spilt them into different arrays. Here the actual working and slow code:

```
 -----> http://viper-7.com/GVRbVp
```

but that method is still slow, i think. At least 3 loops...
i would like to scan one time only the array and create array on the fly, i tried with this:

```
$stray = json_decode('[{"id":"1","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"2","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"3","zona":"Teramo"},{"id":"4","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"5","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"6","zona":"Teramo"},{"id":"7","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"8","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"9","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"10","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"11","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"12","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"13","zona":"Teramo"},{"id":"14","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"15","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"16","zona":"Aquila"},{"id":"17","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"18","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"19","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"20","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"21","zona":"Campobasso"},{"id":"22","zona":"Aquila"},{"id":"23","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"24","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"25","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"26","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"27","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"28","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"29","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"30","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"31","zona":"Pescara"},{"id":"32","zona":"Chieti"},{"id":"33","zona":"Teramo"},{"id":"34","zona":"Teramo"},{"id":"35","zona":"Teramo"},{"id":"37","zona":"Teramo"},{"id":"39","zona":"Pescara"}]',true);

$all_cat = array();
foreach($stray as $row) {
    $item_cat = $row['zona'];
    if($$cat) {                                   /* check if the category array exist */
        $cat = array();                           /* if not, create array */
        if( !in_array($item_cat,$$item_cat) ) {   /* and add the value */
            array_push($$item_cat,$row);
        }
        array_push($all_cat, $cat);               /* add new category to index of categories */
    } else {
        if( !in_array($item_cat,$$item_cat) ) {   /* Otherwise just add the value */
            array_push($$item_cat,$row);
        }
    }

}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($cat,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Using PHP 5.5's [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) or using [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for earlier versions of PHP, followed by [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) could do this much more easily

Comment: Then upgrade...even current debian-stable distributions are shipping newer versions. PHP 5.2 hasn't received security updates for a very long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could simplify it to

```
foreach($stray as $row) {
        if(!isset($$row['zona'])) {
            $$row['zona']=array();
        }
        ${$row['zona']}[] = $row;
}
```

so now your viper-7 would look like

```
$stray = json_decode(...[removed to simplify]...,true);

foreach($stray as $row) {
        if(!isset($$row['zona'])) {
            $$row['zona']=array();
        }
        ${$row['zona']}[] = $row;
}


    echo 'Pescara :<pre style="max-height: 50px; overflow: auto">'.print_r($Pescara,true).'</pre>';
    echo 'Teramo :<pre style="max-height: 50px; overflow: auto">'.print_r($Teramo,true).'</pre>';
    echo 'Chieti :<pre style="max-height: 50px; overflow: auto">'.print_r($Chieti,true).'</pre>';
    echo 'Aquila :<pre style="max-height: 50px; overflow: auto">'.print_r($Aquila,true).'</pre>';
    echo 'Campobasso :<pre style="max-height: 50px; overflow: auto">'.print_r($Campobasso,true).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

For loop through the array. For every element do if else checking for all 3 "zona". If it matches one push it to the respective array within the if and move on to the next element in the array.

Comment: I have understood that alredy xD but in terms of code ? Thanks :D